# How to connect to Oracle DataBase using Protractor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, protractor, node-oracledb

I am trying to connect to oracle database by protractor. I tried several node modules but couldn't able to. Finally I trying with **oracledb** npm. There I am calling getConnnection method the dbConfig as parameter.

dbConfig looks like this.
 dbConfig={
     userName: 'dbName',
      password :  '123123',
connectionString:  'jdbc:oracle:thin:@//ocmuat.abc.net:51521/XTS_SIT.SERVER'
}

After doing all this, I am getting error saying

**ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified**

and after this it is getting closed.

Final error message is like

**Failures:
1) test db connection tests db connection
  Message:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
  Stack:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
        at ontimeout (timers.js:498:11)
        at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:323:5)
        at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:290:5)
  Message:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.**

Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Node-oracledb is not JDBC so you can't use a JDBC connection string.

Just use:

```
dbConfig={ userName: 'dbName', password : '123123', connectionString: 'ocmuat.abc.net:51521/XTS_SIT.SERVER' }
```

There is documentation at https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#notjdbc